# Installing mediaelement.js - what to do?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I want to use mediaelement.js on a website I developed from scratch using php, html etc. I'm struggling to understand how to install the mediaelement.js.

The instructions on
https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/installation.md are as follows:

**1. Install MediaElementJS**

To get the default installation there are several different ways.

```
- Download the package from https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement
- Use a CDN reference; the most popular ones are jsDelivr and cdnjs.
- Through GIT: git clone https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement.git
- Through npm: npm install mediaelement
- Through BOWER: bower install mediaelement
- If you are using Meteor: meteor add johndyer:mediaelement or meteor npm install mediaelement
```

So, apart from the first instruction, I have no idea what they're talking about. Can I please have an *explanation* on how to install mediaelement.js and the best option for somebody who built their website from scratch?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on this topic. I've looked into this further and found out that these are the files I need (which can be found in the build folder, once you've downloaded the package and unzipped it):

```
mediaelement-and-player.min.js
mediaelementplayer.css
mejs-controls.svg
jquery.js (I used my existing jquery file)
```

Then, upload these files to your js directory:

```
jquery.js
mediaelement-and-player.min.js
```

Upload these files to your css directory:

```
mediaelementplayer.css
mejs-controls.svg
```

Link to files on your index page (place them above the link to your custom css)

```html
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/mediaelementplayer.css">
```

Last but not least, add `class="mejs__player"` to your video / audio tag (remove "controls" from tag if you're using it)

Answer (score 0):

Go to
http://www.mediaelementjs.com/
and select click 'Download Player'.
Expand the downloaded zip and look at the content of src.